# Axis Sample AddressBook exception

Tags: java, web-services, ubuntu, wso2, apache-axis

I have 2 questions
I am trying to run a axis 2 sample. In the last part of the instruction file, there is this line which it says, should be run in the terminal(ubuntu), is not working

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=%AXIS2_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext -cp target/classes org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressbook.AddressBookClient.class
```

I am not an expert in this field, and I am not familiar with ubuntu commands. I feel that this is not an ubuntu command
The error I get is, "Invalid Job"

1. Can someone convert this into an ubuntu command?

Since it was not working, I built the jar using,

```
mvn clean install
```

Then I copied the jar file to the servicejars directory under repository, in axis2

Then the axis server says that the jar does not contain the WebServices annotation

"No @WebService annotated service implementations found in the jar: file:/home/dodan/Programs/axis2-1.6.0/repository/servicejars/jaxws-addressbook-1.6.0-client.jar. Service deployment failed."

So I added it to the original java file which did not have that annotation(and the import too)

Yet the axis2 server still sys that there is not webservices annotation
2. Can somebody say whether I have missed anything?

here is the java file I changed

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.Dispatch;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Simple JAX-WS Dispatch client for the address book service implementation.
 */
@WebService
public class AddressBookClient {
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org";
    private static QName QNAME_SERVICE = new QName(NAMESPACE, "service");
    private static QName QNAME_PORT = new QName(NAMESPACE, "port");
    private static String ENDPOINT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/AddressBookImplService.AddressBookImplPort";

private static String ADD_ENTRY_BODY_CONTENTS = 
    "<ns1:addEntry xmlns:ns1=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">" + 
      "<ns1:firstName xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myFirstName</ns1:firstName>" + 
      "<ns1:lastName xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myLastName</ns1:lastName>" + 
      "<ns1:phone xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myPhone</ns1:phone>" + 
      "<ns1:street xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myStreet</ns1:street>" + 
      "<ns1:city xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myCity</ns1:city>" + 
      "<ns1:state xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myState</ns1:state>" + 
    "</ns1:addEntry>";

private static String FIND_BODY_CONTENTS = 
    "<ns1:findByLastName xmlns:ns1=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">" +
      "<ns1:lastName xmlns=\"http://addressbook.jaxws.axis2.apache.org\">myLastName</ns1:lastName>" +        
    "</ns1:findByLastName>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("AddressBookClient ...");

        Service svc = Service.create(QNAME_SERVICE);
        svc.addPort(QNAME_PORT, null, ENDPOINT_URL);

        // A Dispatch<String> client sends the request and receives the response as 
        // Strings.  Since it is PAYLOAD mode, the client will provide the SOAP body to be 
        // sent; the SOAP envelope and any required SOAP headers will be added by JAX-WS.
        Dispatch<String> dispatch = svc.createDispatch(QNAME_PORT, 
                String.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);

        // Invoke the Dispatch
        System.out.println(">> Invoking sync Dispatch for AddEntry");
        String response = dispatch.invoke(ADD_ENTRY_BODY_CONTENTS);
        System.out.println("Add Entry response: " + response);

        System.out.println(">> Invoking Dispatch for findByLastName");
        String response2 = dispatch.invoke(FIND_BODY_CONTENTS);
        System.out.println("Find response: " + response2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Windows syntax for environment variables.

Instead of `%AXIS_HOME%`, you would use `$AXIS_HOME`.

That said, you do not need any version of Axis to learn about web services these days. JAX-WS implementations exist in the JDK for Java 6 and newer.

There's a lot of tutorials around for it.

Comment: Thanks, But I need to learn axis
btw can you convert the whole line into linux en